# Why won't code that initializes a variable interface property in init block compile?

Tags: properties, kotlin

```
interface A {
    var a: Int
}

class AJunior : A {
    override var a: Int

    init {
        a = 3
    }
}
```

It won't compile because

> Property must be initialized or be abstract

But it *is* initialized. I know I can write:

```
override var a: Int = 3
```

But why won't the first example compile? My guess would be that it is a bug or an intentional limitation to simplify compiler implementation, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I see no reason for that not to work. Think it's a bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I reported this as a bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10252), but turns out this behavior is by design because:

> you could have code in the init block that could observe the property in its uninitialized state

Comment: I'm wondering about the same question you asked in that ticket, why would the val case work. If you try to reference 'a' before it's initialized in the init block you get the error 'Variable 'a' must be initialized.' I don't see any reason it wouldn't be the same for a var.

Comment: @eski You might want to join the discussion at the bug tracker.